# Outer and inner automorphism of $\mathrm{Pin}$ groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, lie-groups, automorphism-groups, short-exact-sequences

$\DeclareMathOperator\Inn{Inn}\DeclareMathOperator\Aut{Aut}\DeclareMathOperator\Out{Out}\DeclareMathOperator\Pin{Pin}\DeclareMathOperator\Spin{Spin}\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}\DeclareMathOperator\PSO{PSO}$If I understand correctly, $\Aut\Spin()$ automorphism of Spin groups
splits as a semidirect product $$\Aut\Spin() = \Out\Spin() \ltimes \Inn\Spin().$$  (This is not in general true for automorphism groups, although I am not sure about the situation for Lie groups specifically).

- The inner automorphism group is given by $\Spin()/(\Spin())$, which equals the projective special orthogonal group $\PSO():= \SO()/Z(\SO())$
- The outer automorphism group is  $\Out\Spin()≅\mathbb{Z}_2$
  when $n \geq 4$. When $n=3$, $\Out\Spin()≅0$. When $n=8$, then the $\Out\Spin()≅S_3$.

The definition of Pin group is given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pin_group.

My question is that what is

- the outer and inner automorphism group of $\Pin^{+}(n)$ and $\Pin^{-}(n)$ groups?
- the outer and inner automorphism group of $\Pin^{+}(n,1)$ and $\Pin^{-}(n,1)$  groups?

Comment: Do you have a reference for the outer automorphism groups of Spin?

Comment: I only know this ref: https://oxford.universitypressscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199662920.001.0001/acprof-9780199662920-chapter-8

Comment: @KonradWaldorf: For a connected reductive group $G$ over an algebraically closed field $k$ (of char. 0?), the exact sequence $$1\to {\rm Inn\,} G\to {\rm Aut\,}G\to {\rm Out\,}\to 1$$ admits a splitting.  Namely, any *pinning* of $G$ gives a splitting. See, e.g.,  [Brian Conrad](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/luminysga3smf.pdf), Proposition 1.5.5.

Comment: @KonradWaldorf: I think that the same holds also for connected compact groups over ${\Bbb R}$. For a proof in the special case of a *simply connected simple* compact $\Bbb R$-group, see [Borovoi and Evenor](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.4362), Lemma 4.1.

Comment: @МаринаMarinaS: If you indeed want to get an answer, maybe you could provide definitions of your $\rm Pin$ groups, and maybe some links?

Comment: @KonradWaldorf: The exact sequence in [my comment above](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404215/outer-and-inner-automorphism-of-mathrmpin-groups#comment1036207_404215) should read $$1\to{\rm Inn\,}G\to{\rm Aut\,}G\to{\rm Out\,}G\to 1.$$

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi: this is interesting. But it doesn't seem to help computing the outer automorphism groups, or does it?

Comment: I added it: 
The definition of Pin group is given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pin_group.'

Comment: @KonradWaldorf: Yes, it does! The outer automorphism group of a connected reductive group over an algebraically closed field is canonically isomorphic the the automorphism group its *canonical based root datum*. See Proposition 1.5.5 in the linked paper by Brian Conrad.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi: ok, I see. But neither $Spin$ nor $Pin$ are of this kind.

Comment: @KonradWaldorf: The group $G=\rm Spin$ *is*  of this kind, and there is a canonical isomorphism ${\rm Out\,}G$ onto ${\rm Aut\,}D(G)$, where $D(G)$ is the Dynkin diagram of $G$. By computing ${\rm Aut\,}D(G)$ we immediately obtain the results on ${\rm Out\,}G$ stated by OP.

Comment: @KonradWaldorf: Now let $G$ be one of the groups ${\rm Pin}^+(n)$ and ${\rm Pin}^-(n)$. I think that we have a short exact sequence $$1\to G^0\to G\to\{\pm1\}\to 1,$$ where $G_0\simeq {\rm Spin\,}(n)$. In order to compute ${\rm Out\,}G$, I need to know the isomorphism class of this extension.

Comment: @KonradWaldorf: This isomorphism class can be described by a nonabelian 2-cocycle $(a,f)$ defined as follows. Let $g\in G\smallsetminus G^0$. Then $a=g^2\in G^0$, and $$f={\rm inn}(g)|_{G_0}\,\in\, {\rm Aut\,}(G_0). $$ In particular, this 2-cocycle defines ${\rm lien}(G)\in {\rm Out\,}G$, the image of $f$ in ${\rm Out\,}G$. Note that the lien of $G$ does not depend on the choice of $g$.

Comment: @KonradWaldorf: This nonabelian 2-cocycle $(a,f)$ uniquely determines the isomorphism class of the extension. If you or OP compute for me such a 2-cocycle, then I think I will be able to compute both ${\rm Aut\,}G$ and ${\rm Out\,}G$.

Comment: In [a previous comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404215/outer-and-inner-automorphism-of-mathrmpin-groups#comment1036952_404215) I meant: ${\rm lien}(G)\in {\rm Out\,}G^0$, the image of $f$ in $ {\rm Out\,}G^0$.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi: my concern is why Spin should be a reductive Lie group over an algebraically closed field?

Comment: @KonradWaldorf:  Any connected compact Lie group $G$ over $\Bbb R$ is the group of $\Bbb R$-points  ${\bf G}({\Bbb R})$ of an anisotropic connected reductive algebraic  $\Bbb R$-group $\bf G$. We can consider also the *complex* algebraic group $${\bf G}_{\Bbb C}:={\bf G}\times_{\Bbb R}{\Bbb C}\,.$$  The three groups $G$, $\bf G$, and ${\bf G}_{\Bbb C}$ have the same outer automorphism group. Now ${\bf G}_{\Bbb C}$ is a reductive algebraic group over the algebraically closed field $\Bbb C$.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi: thank you, this was the missing link!